# Calling a web service from Oracle (10g) stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, stored-procedures, cxf

Can anybody point me out on working example of calling web service (e.g. [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) based) from Oracle 10g stored procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using the utl_http package in plsql.

I don't have a self made example ready, but would recommend you have a look at the oracle documentation for utl_http.

A quick google search for "oracle plsql web service utl_http", also showed some examples on the top results, for instance this one: [rapid plsql web service client development using soapui and utl_http](http://technology.amis.nl/blog/3227/rapid-plsql-web-service-client-development-using-soapui-and-utl_http).

As long as the database server has network access to the webservice server you can use it.

Comment: Looks like UTL_DBWS is more applicable for SOAP WS: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/utl_dbws10g.php

Answer (score 2):

One issue you may run into: if the service requires SSL, then you'll need to have a certificate available to the database. That generally means having the Advanced Security option and using Oracle Wallet. For http communications, though, utl_http (and its simpler form, utl_dbws -- database web services -- work pretty well. Marco Gralike's [blog](http://www.liberidu.com/blog/) has a good HOW TO on consuming web services in PL/SQL.